# Is it possible to push a patch set in Gerrit without resetting code-review scores?

Tags: git, gerrit

Sometimes we want to make cosmetic changes to our code (such as correcting a typo or changing a comment) without having to to the code-review process all over again. Is there a command to push a new patch set while retaining the code-review scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can get what you want by configuring your label using the label.LABEL-NAME.copy* project.config options. See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_custom). Pay special attention to the label.Label-Name.copyMaxScore option:

label.Label-Name.copyMaxScore

If true, the highest possible positive value for the label is copied forward when a new patch set is uploaded. This can be used to enable sticky approvals, reducing turn-around for trivial cleanups prior to submitting a change. Defaults to false.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I was wondering if it was possible to do this without having to make server-side changes.

Comment: No, this is not possible.